# When executing configure-ng.py for PyQt4 get "Qt qmake not in path"

Tags: python

I have already loaded SIP and I think I installed it correctly.  Then downloaded PyQt4 and when I try to execute the Configure-ng.py get the error that the qmake file is not in the path of my Python36-32 directory.  Where is the qmake file or executable so that I can move the file to the path and run configure-ng.py?

Comment: Update:  I am using Windows 10 and Python 3.6. Also I ran configure.py for SIP and could not figure how to run make and then install make, so that could be why the qmake is not there.

Answer (score 0):

On Windows "make" is "nmake" instead, and you have to have a Visual Studio and open a cmd from the visual studio to use nmake.

Check out this webpage for nmake information: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd9y37ha.aspx

I recently had this problem, and solved SIP installation following these steps. However I still could not run the configure.py for PyQt4 due to "Qt qmake not in path" error. I don't know why... I did have Qt installed, and the path was included in the system configuration...